# Equivalent class in apex for Java JSONObject class. Any thoughts?

Tags: apex, json

Is there any equivalent class in apex for Java JSONObject class? Please advice.

Java Code:

```
           //create a JSON string 
            String jsonBody =  "{\"secondaryFields\":[],\"entityType\":\"INDIVIDUAL\",\"customFields\":[],\"groupId\":\"418f28a7-b9c9-4ae4-8530-819c61b1ca6c\",\"providerTypes\":[\"WATCHLIST\"],\"name\":\"george w bush\"}";

            // create a JSON object from the JSON string
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonBody);

            //System.out.println(jo.toString());

            String jlen = String.valueOf(jo.toString().length());
```

Comment: yes, @AlexanderBerehovskiy. Actually I want to change few lines of my java code to apex. Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogue is [JSON Generator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm)

Easier way is to create instance of any custom class and do [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

```
public class CustomClass {
    public String name {get; set;}
}

CustomClass ex = new CustomClass();
ex.name = 'MyName';
String str = JSON.serialize(ex);
System.assertEquals('{\"name\":\"MyName\"}', str);
```